# Pros and Cons of an all Ajax Site?

Tags: ajax, web

So I actually saw a full ajax site somewhere (I forget where) and thought it would be something new and fun to try. I used an old site I had built and put it on a new server. With a little bit of jquery and ajax, I was able to make the entire site work on one page load.

My question is, what are some pros and (more likely) cons to this method?

Please note - the site works through a semi clever linking function. Everything works perfectly fine if the user doesn't have javascript enabled, the newly requested page loads like it would on any other website.

More detail -- Say the user loads the homepage of the site, then logs in. When they log in, the login box fades and reappears with user info. Other content on the page loads as necessary upon logging in. If they click a link, lets say "Articles", one column on the homepage slides up and slides back down with the articles. If they click home the articles slide up and the homepage content slides back down. Things like posting comments, viewing profiles, voting on things, etc. are all done through ajax.

Is this a bad method of web design? If so, why?

I am open to all answers/opinions.

Comment: Do you mean that you've written a non-Ajax version of your site for people without JavaScript? Because that's the only way to support people with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @Zarel: no, it's not. Essentially, you build a site that just plain works, even in a text-only browser, then you make it look pretty with a layer of CSS for layout, then you override the default behaviour of things with JavaScript. It's called progressive enhancement, and it not only looks after people with JavaScript disabled, it also handles search engine crawlers and people who need to override CSS for low vision or who use assistive technologies like screen readers.

Comment: @Zarel Stan is exactly right. The javascript overwrites the normal function of things.

@Stan Rogers Nice answer, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @Stan Rogers Isn't that exactly what I said? i.e. what I call the "non-Ajax version" is what you call the "site that just plain works". The rest of your comment was just needless condescension assuming I don't understand the concept of progressive enhancement.

Comment: Not quite. The elements of the site that "just works" are folded into the Ajax version (apart from their UI representation*). There is no creation of a separate application as such; merely an amalgamation of the basic site into a single page (or a set of task-oriented pages). *You don't even have to split the representation (in a non-templated environment) if you use HTML document fragments as the transportation layer; changing the MIME type and includes according to the calling context would suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO, this isn't "bad" or "good".  That depends completely on whether or not the website fulfills the requirements.  Oftentimes, developers working on AJAX-only sites tend to miss the whole negative SEO impact issue.  However, if the site is developed to support progressive enhancement (or graceful degradation depending on your point of view),  which it sounds like you have, then you're good.  Only things to prepare for are times when the AJAX call can't complete as expected (make sure you're dealing with timeouts, broken links, etc) so the user doesn't get stuck staring at a loading icon.  (The kind of stuff you'd have to deal with in any application, really.)

There are plenty of single-page websites out there using heavy JS and AJAX for the UI and they are great.  Specifically, I know of portfolio sites for web designers and web app development teams that use this approach.  Oftentimes, the app feels a bit like a flash app, but without the need for a special plugin.

Answer (score 4):

"Is this a bad method of web design? If so, why?"

Certainly not. In fact, making web-pages behave more like desktop applications, whilst remaining functional to ALL users, is the holy-grail of web-design.

Comment: Until you get a user that doesn't have javascript enabled

Comment: And, until your "desktop" application becomes so enormous that it takes longer to download the monstrosity to manage "state" than it takes to do the one simple task a user went there for.

Answer (score 0):

I say, as long as you consider ALL your users, i.e. mobile/text-only/low bandwidth/small screensizes then you will be fine. Too many developers just do it for their huge 19" screens and 10Mbps, that users to get left behind through almost no fault of their own.

Comment: Screen size is totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: I do like the point of mobile users. I honestly don't know what mobile browsers (if any) can support ajax.

Comment: @CaptOtis I may be late to the party... But I want to say that by now all (or at least most of them) are able to do ajax calls/request (call it like you want :D )

Answer (score 0):

## It depends on the *user*

This relates closely to UX, IMHO, though of course it's on-topic for programming solutions.

### All-AJAX is often called "managing state" 12 years after this Question was asked.

From my experience in:

- Creating a platform for API plugins
- Creating two of my own CMS web apps for different purposes
- Managing many different WordPress.org sites for different purposes
- Managing my own cloud servers for both PHP-AJAX and Node.js doing these calls

...it depends on what is most efficient for users.

Consider these scenarios:

1. Will users be clicking around this website all day long or for at least an hour adjusting many different options and `<form>` inputs?
2. Or will many users visit briefly to perform just a handful of quick tasks?

State-managed / all-AJAX is by far best for scenario 1, with Facebook and Gmail as prime examples.

Whole-page loads are more efficient for scenario 2, like blogs, especially with pages linked directly from search results. That might apply to webstores like Amazon, maybe, where users search Google to find one or two products, then leave.

Philosophically, I've heard that the difference is about *the number of users and traffic*, but I don't quite agree. It's more about *how much clicking and `<form>` sending* the primary target user will be doing.