# Creating a full-ajax website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, performance

When I take a look at popular websites, I see there is just some ajax pages. In other word, I haven't seen a pure-ajax website so fay, Why?

I want to create a full-ajax website. All pages open using ajax, even *contact_us* or *about_us*. So, what is wrong with it? Consider google, yahoo, msn, stackoverflow and etc ..., all of them have used both ajax and http requests *(reloading page)*. Again, why?

I think a full-ajax website will be more user-friendly. Well, Is there any reason for creating some pages as re-loadable?

Comment: You mean having every link on the webpage make an `AJAX` request instead of normally thinking to the next page?

Comment: There are plenty of AJAX only sites if you know where to look.

Comment: SPAs are very common… it's just that creating them in a way that is robust and accessible is a lot of work.

Comment: I guess you can achieve that using Single Page Applications. The very first GET of that page wont be pure Ajax though.

Comment: Here is an answer about the pros and cons of [a full-ajax site](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3747312/2802809)

Comment: Having built a single-page site with AJAX: don't.  Please don't.  It's a headache to do properly for only marginal benefit.  My boss complained that ours took too long to load, but he also didn't want to get rid of the 4000 pixel tall, 2500 pixel wide parallax scrolling backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somehow user friendly. But you also need to be able to get the same conent when loading the HTTP URL and that's proably the biggest problem with these pages.

When you're building a fully featured ajax sit with aother pages and so on, you probalby want every page having it's own URL in the address bar.
This is also needed for going back in the major browsers. You are required to change the URL everytime you get onto a new site. But the visitor must also be able to access this site when entering this URL (you just chaged with javascript) again into his address bar.

This is the biggest problem I could think of.

But you'll also find problems with browser compatibility. For example in IE it's pretty much complicated changing the URL in the address bar due no reload occurs.

I hope I was able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a complete ajax only website, following could be the limiting factors :

1. What if some users turn javascript functionality off on their browser
2. There is no browsing history, bookmarking becomes a pain
3. The accessibility issues because back and refresh button are
       rendered useless

Comment: 2 and 3 *are* solvable, but a right pain in the arse for the programmer.

Comment: 1. Only if you don't have a robust fallback. 2. Only if you fail to use pushState and friends properly. 3. Ditto.

Comment: I agree but as for having a robust fallback, I am assuming you mean essentially having an alternate html only version of the website, that could work but that is not what OP wants